# Is there any way getting a more accurate behavior of the pie menus on hover?

Tags: interface, pie-menu, mouse

The snapping menu specifically is giving me trouble when ever I hover over what I want it just doesn't seem to highlight correctly. I've never been a fan of pie menus they seem to slow me down as my eyes are scanning in all directions rather then just up and down like 2.79 I'm miss clicking more with these new pie menus then I ever did with the old menus in 2.79.

*Is there anything that can be done about this is been a problem since Beta?*

[image: snap pie menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pie Menu Settings**

[image]

> [**Pie Menus**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html#pie-menus)
>
> **Animation Timeout**
>
> Length of animation when opening Pie Menus.
>
> **Tap Key Timeout**
>
> Keystrokes held longer than this will dismiss the menu on release (in 1/100ths of a second).
>
> **Recenter Timeout**
>
> The window system tries to keep the pie menu within the window borders. Pie menus will use the initial mouse position as center for
> this amount of time, measured in 1/100ths of a second. This allows for
> fast dragged selections.
>
> **Radius**
>
> The size of the Pie Menu set with the distance (in pixels) of the menu items from the center of the pie menu.
>
> **Threshold**
>
> Distance from center before a selection can be made.
>
> **Confirm Threshold**
>
> Distance threshold after which selection is made (zero disables).

Setting from python console:

```
>>> C.preferences.view.pie_menu_threshold = 1
>>> C.preferences.view.pie_menu_radius = 20
>>>
```

Comment: I have tweaked these settings in the past little improvement but setting the threshold lower does seem to help a bit. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Pie menus are reliable with cursor near the center.

Their precision decreases the farther you're from the center.
The UI could definitely be improved, but it works reasonably well.

[image]